# iDeal tokenCode too long

Tags: base64, rsa, private-key

I need to make a connection with Rabobank Professional. Before that I have a `RSA private key` created with 2048 bits. When I try to connect I get the error that the token code is too long. The token code is made with `base64_encode ($ message)`.

```
$message = $timestamp.$merchantID.$subid;
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: I guess we need more info about the protocol and what you are doing. What kind of language? PHP? Oh, en welkom op stackoverflow :)